# Why can't I call a prototyped method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/nHetS/)

I have F which inherits from Shape.

```
F.prototype = Shape.prototype;
```

F creates new method with name test.

```
F.prototype.test = function(){return 'test';};
```

I understand that if I write `F.prototype = Shape.prototype;` all the methods which I create in F will be available by other class which inheritance from Shape.

What have I done wrong?

Why do I get errors when I execute the code `alert(B.test());`?

```
function Shape(){}
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {return this.name;};

var F = function(){};
F.prototype = Shape.prototype;
F.prototype.test = function(){return 'test';};


function Triangle(side, height) {
this.side = side;
this.height = height;
}

Triangle.prototype = new F();
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';

var my = new Triangle(5, 10);
alert(my.toString());

var Second_class = function(){};
Second_class.prototype = Shape.prototype;
B.prototype = new Second_class();
alert(B.test());
```

in this example when `F` which inherits from `Shape` and `Triangle` created from `F`
[jsFiddle demo woek well](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/nHetS/1/)

Comment: `B.prototype = new Secend_class();`

Comment: `Secend_class.prototype = Shape.prototype;`

Comment: Yes, but for that to work you'd have to define `B` first. Say, `function B()`.

Comment: `F.prototype = Shape.prototype;` - Why are you doing this?

Comment: I do the same in `F` and it working. why in ` Secend_class` it is not working ?

Comment: if you look on `alert(my.toString());` it working good I will add link to jsFiddle

Comment: [jsFiddle Deno](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/nHetS/)

Comment: You really have too many functions in your example, you should restructure it. Counting them, I see `Shape`, `F`, `Triangle`, `Secend_Class` and (undeclared) `B`. You might want to reduce the complexity to better understand what you are really doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have F which inheritance from Shape.
>
> `F.prototype = Shape.prototype;`

Strictly speaking, you're not. You are overwriting the `prototype` property of the `F` function. To build a real inheritance chain, you would need to use

```
F.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

so that Shape's properties are still available on F instances, but not the other way round (as both prototypes were the same object). So to answer your first question: Yes, you did.

See also [Why wouldn't I use Child.prototype = Parent.Prototype rather than Child.prototype = new Parent(); for Javascript inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11088365/1048572)

> why when I execution the code alert(B.test()); it is not working ?

That's simple to explain. `B` (which you forgot to declare in your example, but let's assume it's a function) is a Function object. You don't have any properties assigned to it.
What you have done is setting it's prototype property (using the `new` keyword also sets up the prototype chain correctly, but accidentally creates an instance - `Object.create` is preferred). So now, any *instances* of `B` will inherit from that prototype object:

```
var b = new B();
b.test();
```