# How to handle object definition vs instantiation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, subclass

I am building a chess application and am running into an issue about the difference between object definition and instantiation in JavaScript. For example, I want to separate my `Board` model (and view) from its representation (a nested array) via a `Matrix` model:

```
var Matrix = function(n, m) {
    // builds an n*m nested array
    // e.g. a 2x3 array would look like this:
    // [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
};

// A setter, which takes a `Point` object and correctly updates the nested array
Matrix.prototype.set = function(pt, obj) {
    this.state[pt.y][pt.x] = obj;
};

// A custom `each` method that iterates over the nested array
Matrix.prototype.each = function(fn) {
  // executes `fn` against every (x,y) in the nested array
};

// etc.
```

And then `Board` looks like this:

```
var Board = function(n, m) {
    Matrix.call(this, n, m);

    // now use `Matrix`'s `set` method to place pieces on the board.
};

Board.prototype = Matrix.prototype;

// etc.
```

My issue is really in the definition of `Board`. When I instantiate a new `Board` object, I would like for it to subclass `Matrix` and then use `Matrix`'s methods to set pieces on the board. But the problem is that `Board` does not have access to `Matrix`'s methods at instantiation, because that relationship is still being defined.

Trying to resolve this issue has clarified the answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224972/why-is-inheritance-only-defined-at-compile-time). It seems like the problem is that `Board` isn't a real subclass of `Matrix`. That relationship is not set until the code actually executes. What is the JavaScript-esque way of handling this relationship?

Comment: `Board.prototype = Matrix.prototype;` is a bad idea. You want `Board.prototype = Object.create(Matrix.prototype);` (with a shim if necessary for the relevant subset of `Object.create`'s functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is that Board does not have access to Matrix's methods at instantiation, because that relationship is still being defined.

No. When you use the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on `Board`, then first the relationship ("prototype chain") will be defined and after that the `Board` constructor function will be called on the new instance, where it can call the `Matrix` function on the instance or add instance properties like `.state`. You can use the prototypically inherited `set` method without any problems in there.

> Looking at [Why is inheritance only defined at compile-time?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224972/why-is-inheritance-only-defined-at-compile-time)

In JavaScript, inheritance is set up at runtime. You can declare the function body (using inherited methods in it), then set the prototype, then instantiate objects.

> ```
> Board.prototype = Matrix.prototype;
> ```

[Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12500637/1048572). You want `Board.prototype = Object.create(Matrix.prototype)`.

Comment: I'm not seeing the reason for the downvotes on this, Bergi's quite correct about what happens when you actually try to *use* the `Board` constructor.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves downvotes. I assume that *"...the constructor will be called on the new instance*" refers to the `Matrix` constructor.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I did refer to the `Board` constructor, actually. It does call `Matrix`, sure.

Comment: Certainly you're not saying: *"When you call new `Board`, then first the relationship ("prototype chain") will be defined and after that the `Board` constructor will be called on the new instance."* I assumed you were referring to `Matrix`.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You might want to read the linked docs about [how the `new` operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I know how `new` works. I was referring to your use of the word *"constructor"* in that sentence to clarify which one you were talking about.

Comment: OK, I did clarify it now :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think your wording is confusing. It makes it sound like `Board` is invoked twice since `new Board` already is a call to `Board`. Whatever. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
Board.prototype = Matrix.prototype;
```

Do this instead so that additions to `Board.prototype` don't affect `Matrix.prototype`.

```
Board.prototype = Object.create(Matrix.prototype);
```

Now `Board.prototype` is an empty object that inherits from `Matrix.prototype`.

---

I see no reason why your object created from `Board` won't have access to methods from `Matrix.prototype`, so I'd assume that you were perhaps overwriting or shadowing the `Matrix.prototype` methods.

The `// etc.` part of your code is likely the issue.