# Can modifying the prototype on a child affect the parent's prototype?

Tags: javascript

While this below implementation seems good, because it allows a child to have its own copy of own members (without having ability to modify parent's own members), plus it uses the prototype chain, so properties won't be recreated for each object instantiation, it is not efficient because the Parent constructor is invoked twice (once for apply and new Parent instantiation):

```
function Parent(a,b,c,d){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.d = d;
}

Parent.prototype.say_a = function(){
  return this.a;
}

Parent.prototype.say_b = function(){
  return this.b;
}

Parent.prototype.say_c = function(){
  return this.c;
}

Parent.prototype.say_d = function(){
  return this.d;
}

Parent.prototype.not_going_to_be_copied = function(){
  console.log(“This function will not be recreated from one object instantiation to the next, making it very efficient.”);
}


function Child(a,b,c,d){
  Parent.apply(this,arguments);
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();
c = new Child("a","b","c","d");
console.log([c.say_a(),c.say_b(),c.say_c(),c.say_d()].join(" "));
```

Stoyan in Javascript Patterns mentions this alternative, which does not invoke Parent constructor at all:

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

However, he says a drawback to this is if one child or grandchild somewhere down the inheritance chain modifies the prototype, it affects all parents and grandparents.

However, I cannot reproduce that claim:

```
function Parent(){}

Parent.prototype.set_a = function(a){
  this.a = a;
}

Parent.prototype.get_a = function(){
  return this.a;
}

function Child(){}
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

var c = new Child();
var p = new Parent();
c.set_a("a");
console.log(c.get_a()); // a
p.set_a("b");
console.log(p.get_a()); // b
console.log(c.get_a()); // a
c.prototype = {};
console.log("after mod " + c.get_a()); // after mod a
console.log("after mod " + p.get_a()); // after mod b
c.get_a = function(){return "am I changing parent?"}
console.log(c.get_a()); // am I changing parent?
console.log(p.get_a()); // b
```

As you can see, no matter how I modify the prototype of Child, it does not affect the prototype of Parent. So am I missing something? Can the children's modification of prototype have affect on the Parent?

Comment: This seems like a good question. It also just seems like you to write more JavaScript code, and experiment with Objects. What is the question here?

Comment: You might want to look at what you're setting the `.prototype` property on in your last example.

Comment: Stoyan says "if one child or grandchild somewhere down the inheritance chain modifies the prototype, it affects all parents and grandparents", however, I cannot reproduce that. I modified the protoype of child in different ways and still the parent has the same prototype values it had. It appears child modification of prototype has no affect on parent, contrarty to what he says.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy can you elaborate?

Comment: @JohnMerlino: it appears you're mistaking what the `.prototype` property does on constructor functions vs what they do on instances (i.e. nothing).

Comment: [`Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;` is just blatantly wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11088365/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `Child.prototype = Parent.prototype` the *same object* is bound to both constructors' prototype property (and is fairly silly, IMOHO). Thus modifying the object known as `Child.prototype` *also* modifies `Parent.prototype` which "affects all" as claimed because both expressions evaluate to the *same object*.

Consider if later on;

```
Child.prototype.hello = "Hello world"
// Noting that
Child.prototype === Parent.prototype  // -> true, as per initial condition
```

Then;

```
var p = new Parent()
p.hello                  // -> "Hello world", showing the "affecting" behavior
```

So it can be see that modifying Child.prototype affected the [prototype] of instances of Parent as well - because the *same object* was modified.

However, the issue isn't being reproduced because one cannot "assign the prototype of an instance" in such a manner. That is, the [prototype] chain is *only* set based of the *constructor's* prototype property (or via Object.create), at time of creating a new instance. Assigning to the prototype property of an instance is .. just assigning a normal property.

```
var c = new Child()
c.prototype = "Hello world"
typeof c.say_a                   // -> "function", didn't assign [prototype]
c.prototype                      // -> "Hello world"
c.__proto__ === Child.prototype  // -> true, in browsers supporting __proto__
```

Comment: That comment confuses me. A string cannot be assigned to the [value of the] constructor. A constructor is just a function, and an identifier is just an identifier - which can evaluate to a value if it is appropriately bound.

Comment: Let me explain it easier. The word "affect" to me means that if I reassign a value to Child, it should change the value of Parent. So look at this: Child.prototype = {}; console.log(Parent.prototype.get_a); After I assigned a blank Object to Child, Parent still thinks it has a get_a function. In other words, Parent.prototype.get_a does NOT produce undefined!

Comment: @JohnMerlino Assigning a *different object* to Child.prototype *does not modify* Parent or the object bound to Parent.prototype. Thus the behavior make sense. The "affecting all" is when the *same object* is mutated, as shown. (This behavior is the same as for other JavaScript properties/objects and has nothing to do with prototypes.)

Comment: I see it now, for some reason, the firefox firebug console was cached for me. When I restarted firefox and tried again, the changes took affect.

Comment: @JohnMerlino Cool, glad it's sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

Is bad because if Child is a Dog and Parent is Animal we can say a Dog is an Animal but we can't say an Animal is a Dog (what about a Snake?).

Here is where it goes wrong

```
var Animal=function(){};
var Snake = function(){};
Snake.prototype=Animal.prototype;
var Dog = function(){};
Dog.prototype=Animal.prototype;
Dog.prototype.bark=function(){console.log('I am barking');};

var aSnake = new Snake();
aSnake.bark();//I am barking ???
```

It's better to use Object.crate to set prototype of Child instead of setting it to an instance of Parent because Parent has instance specific members that should not be on Child and you may have a situation where Parent constructor needs parameters passed that are not available when declaring the Child type (and it's just bad form).

In your code `c.get_a` is shadowing the prototype member and does not affect the prototype. This is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).