# Inheritance with JavaScript and Create Method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to understand How I can do inheritance in JavaScript properly. I can see that in many sources They do it using the create method as follows:

```
var ClassA = function() {
this.name = "class A";
}


ClassA.prototype.print = function() {
console.log(this.name);
}


var ClassB = function() {
this.name = "class B";
this.surname = "I'm the child";
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
....
```

However,  I can see that I can extend from the parent object (ClassA) without  using the create method, like that:

```
ClassB.prototype = ClassA.prototype;
```

So, Could Anyone tell me, why should I use the "Create" global method, as many examples do? In addition, in many examples They call the constructor of the base class (ClassA.call(this)), but I can see it is not really necessary. So?, I would appreciate your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588255/can-modifying-the-prototype-on-a-child-affect-the-parents-prototype

Comment: If you add a method to ClassB's prototype, it will also be added to ClassA's prototype as they reference the same object. Using Object.create creates a new object so adding methods to ClassB's prototype will not affect ClassA's prototype.

Comment: Try to give `ClassB` its own `print` method and see it fail without `Object.create`.

Comment: Thank you. your answers were precise and concise. Likewise, I could get a deeper information in the other question already asked.