# For inheritance with JavaScript, is it better to reference or copy the parent's prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Currently I implement inheritance in my JavaScript libraries as follows:

```
parent = function() { };
parent.prototype.hello = function() { alert('parent'); };

child = function() { };
child.prototype = parent.prototype;
```

However, I've noticed when I override a function in a child "class's" prototype, it undesirably overrides the parent's prototype as well:

```
child.prototype.hello = function() { alert('child'); }

(new parent()).hello();  // alerts "child" --> undesirable
(new child()).hello();   // alerts "child" --> desirable
```

And if I delete something from the child's prototype

```
delete child.prototype.hello;
```

then the parent's prototype is undesirably affected. So, maybe

```
child.prototype = parent.prototype;
```

is not the best way of implementing inheritance? Instead of making child "classes" reference the parent prototype, perhaps it would make more sense to *copy* the parent prototype to the child prototype?

```
_.extend(child.prototype, parent.prototype);
```

Comment: yes. you right. it's not nice when children mess up with parents. proper extending is the way to go.

Comment: I have yet to see any case where `child.prototype = parent.prototype;` is correct. You probably want `child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);`

Comment: Use `Object.create`. See [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why wouldn't I use Child.prototype = Parent.Prototype rather than Child.prototype = new Parent(); for Javascript inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11088365/1048572)

Comment: It's not the same question. They are asking whether to create a new instance of the parent object as the child's prototype, while I am asking whether to copy the parent's prototype.

Comment: Common patterns for constructor functions, prototype, inheritance and mix ins are explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`child.prototype = parent.prototype;` is incorrect, for the reason you've detailed in your question.

Using [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) isn't want you want, either. Consider that a change in an "inherited" parent prototype property will *not* cause a change in the child:

```
// perform extension
_.extend(child.prototype, parent.prototype);

// parent later gains new property after extension
parent.prototype.parentProp = function() { alert("new"); };

(new parent()).parentProp();  // alerts "new" --> desirable
(new child()).parentProp();   // error; doesn't exist --> undesirable
```

You probably want `child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);` This says: "Store a new object in `child.prototype`. This new object uses the `parent.prototype` object as its own prototype." This causes real inheritance to happen, because when a `child` instance wants a property, it first looks in its own properties, then in its immediate prototype (`child.prototype`), and then in its prototype's prototype (`parent.prototype`).

**Prototype chains**

- When using `child.prototype = parent.prototype`, the prototype chains for the instances look like:

  ```
  { child instance } ==> { only prototype }

  { parent instance } ==> { only prototype }
  ```

  where `only prototype` is the shared object referred to by both `child.prototype` and `parent.prototype`.
- When using `_.extend(child.prototype, parent.prototype)`, the child prototype and parent prototypes are different, but there's no direct inheritance. Changing the parent prototype doesn't change the child at all, since we merely copied the parent prototype's properties into the child prototype at one single point in time.

  ```
  { child instance } ==> { child.prototype }

  { parent instance } ==> { parent.prototype }
  ```
- With `child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);` you actually have *inheritance* happening from parent to child prototype:

  ```
  { child instance } ==> { child.prototype } ==> { parent.prototype }

  { parent instance } ==> { parent.prototype }
  ```