# JavaScript inheritance not working as expected

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have my master object:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.canTalk = true;
}
```

Method I want all sub-objects to inherit:

```
Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    if( this.canTalk ) {
        console.log( 'Hi, I am ' + this.name );
    }
}
```

Sub-object that inherits from `Employee`

```
  var Employee = function( name, title) {
        Person.call( this );
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }
```

Instantiation:

```
var robert = new Employee( "Robert Rocha", "Software Developer" );
robert.greet();
```

`greet()` gets the error: `Uncaught TypeError: robert.greet is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Employee prototype is not inheriting from the Person prototype.  You are calling the Person constructor, but not getting any of the data from the Person prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend the prototype of `Employee`.

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```

Comment: I thought that simply assigning a value to the prototype would cause all sub-objects to inherit.

Comment: Ahh ok so I think I understand. The `Object.prototype` statement is like saying, "I want to extend blah to this current object" so to speak, and the Object.create()` specifies what object it is that you are extending?

Comment: not really. `Object.prototype` already exists so I'll use `MyFunc.prototype` is I want all instances of `MyFunc` to have these properties. `Object.create` is merely copying it.

Comment: @RobertRocha Just fyi, to get the actual prototype of any given object, you do `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`.

Answer (score -2):

The key thing you need to do is set the prototype chain.  You correctly called the parent constructor and passed it the value of this.  You can do this very simply:

```
Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

However, now when you add a method to Person, Employee will have access to it as well.  If you have a special use case this will work but typically you won't want to do this.

Using the more common method, and when you add a method to Employee.prototype it will not be available to Person.

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Note that you are still over-writing Employee.prototype and need to define methods after this over-write.

Comment: It "works", yes, but is a very bad practise - you're not setting a prototype *chain* here

Comment: Just for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088365/why-wouldnt-i-use-child-prototype-parent-prototype-rather-than-child-prototype-new-parent