# Which variants of javascript inheritance we should use and why?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I don't understand which variants of inheritance we should use. I even don't know if there is a difference between them.
I have a simple JavaScript inheritance example:

```
function MyObject(a){
    this.a = a;
}

function MyObjectChild(a, b){
    MyObject.call(this, a);
    this.b = b;
}

MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);

var myObj = new MyObjectChild(1, 2);

console.log(myObj.a + " " + myObj.b);
```

result will be "1 2".

But this row:

```
MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);
```

we can write in 10 different ways:

```
MyObjectChild.prototype = new MyObject();
MyObjectChild.prototype = MyObject.prototype;
MyObjectChild.prototype = MyObject.prototype.prototype;
MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject);
MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);
MyObjectChild.prototype.prototype = new MyObject();
MyObjectChild.prototype.prototype = MyObject.prototype;
MyObjectChild.prototype.prototype = MyObject.prototype.prototype;
MyObjectChild.prototype.prototype = Object.create(MyObject);
MyObjectChild.prototype.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);
```

All of them will work! Can somebody explain which variants we should use and which one we should not?

Comment: I just say never mind the hassle with es5 class declarations. Now and for the future I use the es6 added `class Name {}`. If necessary I compile to es5 or simply use strict mode. The new class declarations are more standardized, easier to understand and much more clean.

Comment: "*All of them will work!*" - Nope. In fact, none of your alternatives does work, they all do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it a million different ways because it does not do anything in this situation.

Try your code without 
`MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);` and it still works.

On the line `MyObject.call(this, a);` you are calling MyObject as a function giving it the same `this` reference as in your `MyObjectChild` constructor. Therefore, you are adding the values of `a` and `b` to the `MyObjectChild` object directly when you create the `myObj` object.

To answer your question: You should use neither.

---

You can however, in your example, achieve the desired effect like this...

```
function MyObject(a){
    this.a = a;
}
MyObject.prototype.foo = "ta da";

function MyObjectChild(a, b){
    MyObject.call(this, a);
    this.b = b;
}

MyObjectChild.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);

var myObj = new MyObjectChild(1, 2);

console.log(myObj.foo); // ta da
```

This way all instances created using these constructors (such as `myObj`) will inherit properties from `MyObject.prototype`.

**EDIT:**

Originally using `MyObjectChild.prototype = MyObject.prototype;` was suggested. This would mean all instances inherit properties from the same prototype object.

Credit to *Bergi* below for pointing out this is probably not what you intend, as adding properties to `MyObjectChild`s prototype would then be inherited by `MyObject`.

`Object.create(MyObject.prototype)` instead creates a new object (to which you may add properties that only `MyObjectChild` instances inherit) while still inheriting properties from `MyObject`s prototype.

Comment: [`MyObjectChild.prototype = MyObject.prototype;` is not inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11088365/1048572). I don't think that's the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Bergi. I now see your point about the _desired effect_. Will edit the above.