# How should I convert prototype initialization into ES6

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ecmascript-6, prototype, es6-class

I am attempting to create a Google Maps Overlay View. I have this code here in ES5 telling me to initialize an object in my marker prototype like below:

```
MainMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

How do I exactly convert this to ES6?

For inheritance, such as `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`, to this in ES6, we can write like

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }
}
```

But how to come about with the first one?

Comment: maps api docs now have a complete example using OverlayView in ES6: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this code here in ES5 telling me to initialize an object in my marker prototype like below:
>
> ```
> MainMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
> ```

This [never was the correct way in ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)<sup>1</sup> anyway, so don't try to keep bad practises around.
Just go for

```
class MainMarker extends google.maps.OverlayView { … }
```

<sub>1: In this specific case, it doesn't make a difference whether `new` or `Object.create` is used, the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) explicitly state that "*The `OverlayView` constructor is guaranteed to be an empty function.*". Google likely used the former syntax in their examples because it's more backwards-compatible.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `Child.prototype = Parent.prototype` vs `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`, I believe `Object.create` creates a deep copy of `Parent.prototype` but does not initialize. In this case `Child.prototype = new Parent()`, does it not initialize the **Child's** prototype object?

Comment: Best practice or not, OP is asking specifically about ES5

Comment: @cs1193 the first doesn't create a copy at all but just uses the same object. `Object.create()` does create a new object that inherits from the argument. `new Parent()` would indeed initialise the prototype object, which we don't want. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572?Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088365/why-wouldnt-i-use-child-prototype-parent-prototype-rather-than-child-prototype-new-parent) for details

Comment: @terpinmd He asked how to convert it to ES6. Of course one could just carry on with the same code - all ES5 is valid ES6 so no conversation necessary - but that's not what you should do.

Comment: @Bergi @terpinmd in my case, I would like to initialize the Object `MainMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();` to my prototype, I wouldn't want to inherit it to a another class. If that is the case, how would I do that in ES6? This is in accordance with Google Maps API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: @cs1193 The ES6 equivalent of that is `const MainMarker = Object.setPrototypeOf(class { … }, new google.maps.OverlayView)`. However I've further researched the issue and am 100% certain that this is a mistake on Google's side. They explicitly state that they want you to *subclass* the `OverlayView`. I suspect they used the wrong syntax because it doesn't need ES5 `Object.create` (and works in ES3), and because it didn't matter when all overlays are singletons.