# In javascript, (CONSTRUCTOR).prototype.constructor = (ANOTHER CONSTRUCTOR) called asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I am learning about javascript prototypal inheritance, and have hit a weird behaviour. Can someone please help clearing up confusion below.

It appears that the statement:
Magazine.prototype.constructor = Magazine; 
is executing before the object mag1 is created

```
//Book constructor.
function Book (title, author, year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
}

//Magazine constructor.
function Magazine(title, author, year, month) {
    //We create the same properties/functions as book in here using the call method (This is not  inheritance here)
    Book.call(this, title, author, year);
    this.month = month;
}

Magazine.prototype = Book.prototype;

const mag1 = new Magazine('Magazine 1', 'John Doe', '2017', 'January');
console.log(mag1);  //mag1.__proto__  object has Book constructor here

//But if we enable the commented line below, mag1.__proto__  object above, shows Magazine constructor, even though the the line below is executed afterwards.
//Is the following line executing asynchronously?

//Magazine.prototype.constructor = Magazine;
console.log(mag1);
```

I expect the first console output of mag1, **proto**  object should have Book constructor.

and second console output of mag1, **proto**  object should have Magazine constructor.

Comment: [`Magazine.prototype = Book.prototype;` is your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088365/why-wouldnt-i-use-child-prototype-parent-prototype-rather-than-child-prototype-new-parent)

Comment: The console tools only evaluate parts of objects when you expand them. (There might be a little [i] icon explaining that.) By the time you do so, the change has already happened.

Comment: (To see the right order, you can log something that doesn’t need to be expanded, like `console.log(mag1.__proto__.constructor.name)`.)

Comment: @Ry- Thankyou loads, changed code as below and see the desired result 
`function Book (title, author, year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
}


function Magazine(title, author, year, month) {
    Book.call(this, title, author, year);
    this.month = month;
}

Magazine.prototype = Book.prototype;

const mag1 = new Magazine('Magazine 1', 'John Doe', '2017', 'January');
console.log(mag1.__proto__.constructor.name)
Magazine.prototype.constructor = Magazine;
console.log(mag1.__proto__.constructor.name)`